# Is there any built in algorithms or library available in C# to calculate the probability functions?

Tags: c#, algorithm, machine-learning

How to code the following methods?

```
dbinom(k, size=n, prob=P)
pbinom(k, size=n, prob=P)
.
.
.
```

I wonder if in **C#** there are some similar *built-in algorithms* or some *libraries* available?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing built-in. You have to either implement yourself, or get any lib that gets the job done. Questions to find those libs however are off-topic here.

Comment: Factorial in fact is not *that costly*, if `n` is *large*, try *Stirling approximation*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @Coder: you can try https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ but `dbinom` can be easily implemented manually

Comment: Some interesting information is provided on SE/Mathematics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460756/can-a-binominal-or-multinomial-coefficient-be-computed-efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try to create the routine yourself. First, since we are going to operate with *huge* numbers (facrorials) let's use *logarithms*;
instead of

```
 dbinom(k, n, p) = 
   = n! / k! / (n - k)! * pow(p, k) * pow(1 - p, n - k)
```

we compute

```
 log(dbinom(k, n, p)) = 
   = log(n!) - log(k!) - log((n - k)!) + k * log(p) + (n - k) * log(1 - p)
```

and finally, *exponentiate* it. As far as I can see from the question the *main difficulty* is `log(n!).` We can precompute it for *small* `n` and use [Stirling Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
 in case of *large arguments*:

```
public static class Distributions {
  private static Dictionary<int, double> s_LogFactorials = new Dictionary<int, double>();

  static Distributions() {
    long p = 1;
    s_LogFactorials.Add(0, 0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) 
      s_LogFactorials.Add(i, Math.Log(p *= i));
  }

  private static double LogFactorial(int value) {
    if (s_LogFactorials.TryGetValue(value, out double result))
      return result;

    return Math.Log(2 * Math.PI * value) / 2 + 
           value * Math.Log(value) - 
           value + 
           Math.Log(1 + 1 / 12.0 / value);
  }

  public static double dbinom(int k, int n, double p) {
    if (p < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(p));
    else if (p > 1)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(p));

    if (k < 0 || n < 0 || k > n)
      return 0.0;
    else if (p == 0 || p == 1.0)
      return 0.0;

    double logResult = LogFactorial(n) - LogFactorial(k) - LogFactorial(n - k) + 
                       k * Math.Log(p) + (n - k) * Math.Log(1 - p);

    return Math.Exp(logResult);
  }
}
```

Some tests:

```
Distributions.dbinom(   5,    9, 0.30) == 0.0735138179999999
Distributions.dbinom(  21,   45, 0.48) == 0.116657747325863
Distributions.dbinom(  63,  121, 0.54) == 0.0661504080311266
Distributions.dbinom(1163, 2019, 0.52) == 5.15538389581199E-08
```

Finally, if you insist on math library, you can try [Math.Net](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

Comment: Isn't this line supposed to be `s_LogFactorials.Add(i, Math.Log(p *= i));`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks a lot for your help.